# Sending files as attachment using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have list of excel files in a directory. I'm trying to email those files as attachment. However, when I open the email, I could see only one file as attachment. The below script is not attaching multiple files as attachment.

```
ls *.xls;
#echo "Test Email" | mailx -s "Testing File Conv" -a *.xls test@testmail.com
```

Will the above script work?

Comment: I don't use `mailx` but try repeating `-a` for a couple of files, i.e. `mailx -s "Subject" -a file1.xls -a file2.xls ...` and see if it works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to write a script for this. at first create `test.txt`.

```
ls *.xls -1 > test.txt
```

then run this script :

```
while read line
do
mailx -s "Subject" -a ${line} -s "files" ${mail_from} << EOM

Hi, Sent files

EOM

done<test.txt
```

Comment: Using the output of `ls` to parse and using `read` without a `-r` switch, are both bad practices.

Comment: You simply want `for line in *.xls`; also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 3):

An array can be built to hold all the attachment options for each file like this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Produces no result if no match for pattern
shopt -s nullglob

# Captures recipients from script arguments
recipients=("$@")

# Populates aray with xls file paths
xls_files=(./*.xls)

# If there are xls files
if [ "${#xls_files[@]}" -gt 0 ]; then

  # Declare an array to store mailx attachment options
  attach_option=()

  # Creates an attachment option for each file to be attached
  for file in "${xls_files[@]}"; do
    attach_option+=(-a "$file")
  done

  # Sends mail with all the attachment options
  mailx -s "Testing File Conv" "${attach_option[@]}" "${recipients[@]}"
fi
```